# Project compiles in XCode but XCodeBuild produces error "No architectures ..."

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

My project compiles fine when build within Xcode but it fails when I try to build it using xcodebuild, the last line of output is:

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET XXX OF PROJECT YYY WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).
```

As the last line is mentioning architectures I checked the architectures section in Build Settings and its set to Standard(armv7, armv7s).

I culprit is the active arch=x86_64, if I change the Xcode setting to build active architectures = NO then its ok.

But where is the active architecture being set, and why is the default value x86, and should I change it to be something else or is it the correct thing to do to work around this by setting build active architecture to NO?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same and solved it setting "Architectures" to Standard (armv7, armv7s) and "Build Active Architecture Only" to No in my project build settings and in all of its subprojects. It is also possible to override those values in the command line like this:

```
xcodebuild -project YourProject.xcodeproj -scheme YourScheme ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but as I said I already have the solution: "if I change the Xcode setting to build active architectures = NO then its ok." I'm asking for background info on why the active architecture is set to x86 and if this solution is acceptable and why or why not. I'm not content for it to work, I want to understand things in greater detail - the whys and whats etc. Cheers